# How to display multiple attributes items of a model in list item in rails active admin index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

In a model which has multiple attributes comes from a many to many relationship is shown with comma separated in active admin index page.

```
index do
  # other columns goes here
  column('Product Categories') { |p| p. product_categories.pluck(:category_title).join(', ') }
end
```

Now I want to display all of them(category_title)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to print that in the list you should use the following:

```
index do
  # other columns goes here
  column('Product Categories') { |p| p.product_categories.pluck(:category_title).join('<br />').html_safe
end
```